# Unable to install google chrome duo to error: sqlite3.dll wasn't found

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, windows-10

Yesterday i downloaded emulator from some shady website and it came with a virus. I downloaded malware bytes quickly after and quarantined the virus. but after that my google chrome was buggy so I decided to reinstall it. but after I deleted it i couldnt install it any more. error was:
"the code execution cannot proceed because sqlite3.dll was not found. reinstalling the program may fix this problem."
i downloaded sqlite3 using youtube tutorial. setted up its path and everything. when I write sqlite3 in command bar it shows its version and i can use its commands but I'm still unable to install google chrome :/[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

only need to delete folder Google allocated C:\Program Files (x86)\ and again install google chrome